# Polymorphic Lookups - How to pull the

Tags: apex, soql, tasks, polymorphism

I have a query in my class where I'm trying to pull in the position name from a task that is being created on an application.

So I have Position, Application, and Candidate.  The task is created on Application, and I would like to pull in the position people are applying to.

Here's the query:

```
public List<Task> contactTasks {
    get {

        return [SELECT Id, Subject, ActivityDate, WhatId, Description FROM Task 
                        WHERE Subject like 'Rejected%' AND WhoId =: application.Candidate_Contact__c
                             ORDER BY ActivityDate];

    }
}
```

Is there a way to grab the position?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature in the works that allows you to query this data. It is currently a preview feature and can't be used in production code (yet). You can see the documentation for [TYPEOF](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm). Without TYPEOF, you have to perform two queries; one to obtain the tasks, and another to grab the contact or lead. Conversely, you could use a sub-query to query from lead or contact and their tasks.

### TYPEOF

```
SELECT Id, Subject, ActivityDate, WhatId, Description, TYPEOF WhoId WHEN Contact THEN Position__c END FROM Task WHERE WhoId = :application.Candidate_Contact__c
```

### Sub-query

```
SELECT Id,Name,Position__c,(SELECT Id, Subject, Activitydate, WhatId, Description FROM Tasks) FROM Contact WHERE Id = :application.Candidate_Contact__c
```

Comment: Thanks!  Can it only be done from Contacts or Leads?  The Tasks are being created on the custom object Application__c

Comment: For using WhatId, the same general principle applies. You can use subqueries and typeof on any object.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that the feature is coming out in Winter 13 to allow the lookups.